# How to solve for the total derivative with respect to a parameter for a system of two embedded functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My problem has two embedded functions:

$$E = F(x, P)$$

$$P = f(x, E)$$

where $x$ is a parameter.

I want to sign the total derivative of $E$ wrt to $x$, i.e. $dE/dx$.

Can this be solved? If so, is it correct to simply proceed as follows?

$$dE = F_1dx + F_2dP$$

$$dP = f_1dx +f_2dE $$

where $F_1$ is the partial derivative of $F$ wrt the first argument $x$, and $F_2$ is the partial derivative wrt a change in $P$. Similarly for $f_1$ and $f_2$. Substituting:

$$dE = F_1dx + F_2(f_1dx +f_2dE)$$

$$dE(1 - F_2f2) = (F_1 + F_2f_1)dx $$

$$dE/dx =  (F_1 + F_2f_2)/(1 - F_2f_1)$$

I have priors on all the partial derivatives: $F_2 < 0$ and $f_1 > 0$ so the denominator is positive. The numerator is negative, so if above calculations are legit $dE/dx < 0$. Thanks.

Comment: The calculation is legit.

Comment: The calculation is legit, but is the notation? I really don't get the whole pushing infinitesimals around algebraically if all you could have done is $E'=F_1+F_2P'$ and $P'=f_1+f_2E'$ and then solve for $E'$. But that's more of a personal gripe than any substantial criticism.